# Wieland's method for triphenylamine bromination

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm looking for a Wieland's paper on triphenylamine bromination. I've found other papers referencing it [like this](http://www2.chemia.uj.edu.pl/~grolik/1/11.pdf) but I don't find the actual paper.

Does someone know where could I find it? Or whats Wieland's method all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the reference you supplied the Wieland paper is Chem. Berichte **40** (1907) 4278

The bromination method (3 eq of Bromine in chloroform slowly added to a chloroform soln of triphenylamine) in the experimental section of the reference you supplied appears to be Wieland's method - it is referenced as such

Comment: Thanks ! Side question: Do you know what is (or where I can find) the mecanism for this reaction ?

Comment: Straightforward electrophilic substitution by Br+. After the first Br goes in that phenyl is less activated towards a second substitution so the 2nd phenyl reacts preferentially, then the third.